# Inserting document into Mongodb with NodeJs returns document but it is not in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a weird issue where I have a test to see prove that you cannot create a new user if a user with the same name/email exists, however it always seems to fail. However when I look at the first step which  adds a user to the database with the details expected, it inserts and calls back with the document:

```
[ { Username: 'AccountUser',
    Email: 'some@email.com',
    CreatedDate: Mon Sep 22 2014 12:52:48 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time),
    _id: 54200d90d0a34ffc1565df13 } ]
```

So if I do a console.log of the documents returned from insert thats what I get which is ok, and the _id has been set by mongo which is correct, so I know the call succeeded, and there was no errors.

However if I then go and view the database (MongoVUE) that collection is empty, so I am a bit baffled as to why this is happening.

I am using pooled mongodb connections (i.e setting up during app setup then using `app.set("database_connection", database);`. So I am a bit baffled as to why this is happening?

Here is some example code, which is part of larger code but basically is contained within promises:

```
// Point of connection creation
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var connectionCallback = function (err, database) {
    if (err) { reject(err); }
    resolve(database);
};

try
{ mongoClient.connect(connectionString, connectionCallback); }
catch(exception)
{ reject(exception); }

// Point of usage
var usersCollection = connection.collection("users");
usersCollection.insert(userDocument, function(err, docs) {
    if(err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(docs);
    resolve(docs[0]);
});
```

So I create the connection and pass back the database for use elsewhere, then at the point of inserting I get the connection, get the collection and then insert into it, and log the documents added, which is what is in the above log output.

Also finally running:

- Windows 8.1
- Node 0.11.13
- npm mongodb latest
- MongoDB 2.6.1

Comment: No. Weird breakages are not common with well tested software. Perhaps should **show some code** in your question so we can tell you what **you** are doing wrong.

Comment: Indeed, however given that I get an _id back in the document it does imply that there is an insertion, however none appears in the database. Will update the question to show some code.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking into the correct database and not the test database?

Comment: There is only 1 db being used, the connection string is based upon the environment, which is "dev" in this case, however to answer the question yes. It worries me that someone being pissy gets +2 upvotes and someone stating the obvious gets a +2, and the question itself gets a vote to close...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer I was hoping for, but I restarted the computer (rare occurrence) and the issue no longer occurs. I have no idea what was causing it and I am still slightly worried incase it happens again, but for now I am up and running again.